# Testcafe Role change issue

Tags: testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe, user-roles

I use in my website an user 
BC3Tester. I set this role. 
After login out with this Role, the Role is not useable anymore. Testcafe will fail to use the Role again.

Sample.

- BC3Tester
- GTester
- BC3Tester <- Fail

Sample

- BC3Tester1
- GTester
- BC3Tester2
- BC3Tester3
- BC3Tester1 <- Fail.

It looks that it is not possible to use any role again after log out on the website. 
The website uses a cookie to store the data. I assume that the log out will delete the cookie and also a master session for the user. Maybe this is the issue with the session?

Amazing is that new roles will always work, but I do not want to write a random role generator.

Comment: The Roles mechanism in TestCafe is intended to switch between roles during the tests, so your scenario should work correctly. The logging out also should not affect Role - when Role is initialized with cookies, they are stored in it and cannot be removed on role switching.

I do not see any problems with your scenario, it looks valid, so I suppose that there is some error in your test code or your site has some specifics.
Would you please share your project and your test code or create a sample to demonstrate the issue?

Comment: Alex this web project is not public so if there is a debugging or real sample is needed it have to be done without this public board in case of access data. Who I can contact with email to arrange a non public communication?

Comment: You can send the sample project to support@devexpress.com. Our policy prevents us from accessing internal resources without prior written approval from a site owner, so if you want us to research the problem directly on your side, please ask the website owner to send us a written confirmation to the same e-mail. It must permit DevExpress personnel to remotely access the website and its internal resources for research/testing/and debugging purposes.